# Crypto block request in express and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cryptography

I've the follow coding that generate encryptation for password user before save in database. I tried sync and async methods. Follow synchronous code:

```
function generateCrypto(value) {
    let randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    let salt = randomBytes.toString('hex');
    let keyLength = 255;
    let iterations = 5;
    let digest = 'sha256';

    let cryptValue= crypto.pbkdf2Sync(value, salt, iterations, keyLength, digest);
    return cryptValue;
}
```

I tried a small iterations with different value in case a loop that block execution. Another thing I tried execute the code in REPL and  work.

What could be wrong, I should open a issue in node repo?

Comment: Your code works for me, what is the problem, tell us more, please

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You don't clearly describe the problem.  What result are you expecting?  What result do you get?  What is the context for this code?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for that, I think everyone here can read code and know what is expected. So the result I expected is a cryptografed password, and don't get any result. The process block in `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`. But I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `password` MUST be a string and the `password`was number values. What block the execution without any errors.